# Converting all breaklines and newlines to a single breakline

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to sanitize user input and ensure there are no redundant breaklines or newlines. Currently, I'm having trouble because of the fact that users can use three main ways to "breakline"

```
\n
<br/>
<br />
```

And there are many variants of `<br>`. As these are all acceptable formats to breakline in HTML. I've tried searching online and using previous regex expressions, but they don't seem to be catching the multiple breaklines to the tricky

```
<br/><br /><BR>< br >
```

In order to make things simpler, I thought of converting the whole string to only standardized breaklines, so every `\r` and `\n` would become some form of `<br/>` or `<br />`, and this might be easier to parse, by doing something like:

```
$string = 'some input with breaklines and newlines';
$string = nl2br($string);
$string = preg_replace(regex_expression, replacement, $string);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know regex very well. How can I create a regex expression to remove these variants of all breaklines and keep them into one? These are the previous ones I've used:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n\n", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/(<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/', '<br/>', $text);
```

Or, better, is there a more efficient and used practice way to accomplish this? I'm guessing most user-input sites have some sort of this system in place

Here is an example of a string I found slipping through:

```
String testing for newlines.<br/><br />
<br/><br />
<br/><br />
Edit 1<br/><br />
<br/><br />
<br/><br />
Edit 3:<br/><br />
Removed redundant newlines
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\r|\n|(\<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>))+/i", "<br/>", $text);
```

Replacing all multiples of \r, \n, `<[ ]br[ ][/][ ]>` and `<[ ]BR[ ][/][ ]>` to a single `<br/>`